# jQuery: Determine from which <tr> the function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a knockout grid that looks like this (nothing special):

[image: knockoutjs grid editable]

When I click Edit, it must determine in which `<tr>` it was called. For Example I click edit on the first user, it must log in console "1", and so on.

**My table's code:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" data-bind='visible: users().length > 0'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserId</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th />
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: users'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label data-bind="text: UserId" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: Username' />
                <label data-bind="text: Username" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: FirstName' />
                <label data-bind="text: FirstName" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: LastName' />
                <label data-bind="text: LastName" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: Email' />
                <label data-bind="text: Email" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input data-bind='value: Date' />
                <label data-bind="text: Date" />
            </td>
            <td class="tools">
                <a class="Apply" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.applyUser">Apply</a>
                <a class="Edit" href="#" data-bind="click: $root.editUser">Edit</a>
                <a class="Update" href="#" data-bind='click: $root.updateUser'>Update</a>
                <a class="Delete" href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeUser'>Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is my attempt:**

```
$('a.Edit').click(function () {
                    var rowIndex = $(this).parent()
                                          .parent()
                                          .children()
                                          .index($(this).parent());
                    console.log('Row: ' + rowIndex);
                });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have multiple tbody's in your generated markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather use `.closest()` for traversing to closest tr parent.

**IF tr elements are not siblings of each other:** pass that object to method `.index()` on tr collection:

```
 $('tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
```

**IF tr elements are siblings of each other:**

```
 $(this).closest("tr").index()
```

Comment: Or simply `$(this).closest("tr").index()`

Comment: that wont work if tr elemets are not direct sibling, updated.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done this as below-

**By giving a class to parent tr-**

`<tr class="parent">`

**And then-**

`$(this).closest('tr.parent').index()`

Because if the case is nested `tr(s)` then `parent()` wont' be working for longer.